# arithmetic expression into a portion of a python regression formula

Tags: python, model, regression

| food | weight |
| --- | --- |
| 61 | 115 |
| 76 | 139 |
| 41 | 86 |
| 70 | 127 |
| 85 | 149 |
| 91 | 160 |

My question is kinda simple, I want to run a linear model into python and the model is something like this::

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
```

```
model = smf.ols('weight ~ food + food ^ 2', data = data).fit().summary()
```

the problem is that I want to use the power of the food variable without create a new variable in the Data.Frame, but if a run the model like above, the system shows me an error.  I do the same thing in R and it works:

```
model <- lm(weight ~ concentrado + I(concentrado ^ 2), data = data)
summary(model)
```

if you guys note, in R there is a parameter I() that helps to do the arithmetic expression that I want to reproduce in python. If anybody can help me, I I would appreciate it so much, so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Python uses the `**` symbol for exponentiation.

```
model = smf.ols('weight ~ food ** 2', data = data).fit().summary()
```